# Dataframe sorting does not apply when using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I need to sort panda dataframe df, by a datetime column my_date. IWhenever I use .loc sorting does not apply.

```py
df = df.loc[(df.some_column == 'filter'),]
df.sort_values(by=['my_date'])
print(dfolc)
# ...
# Not sorted! 
# ...
```

```py
df = df.loc[(df.some_column == 'filter'),].sort_values(by=['my_date'])
# ...
# sorting WORKS!
```

What is the difference of these two uses? What am I missing about dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you didn't perform an operation in-place: you should have used either `df = df.sort_values(by=['my_date'])` or `df.sort_values(by=['my_date'], inplace=True)`.

In the second case, the result of `.sort_values()` was saved to df, hence printing `df` shows sorted dataframe.

Comment: So the difference is that `df.sort_values(by=['my_date'])` returns an updated `df` but doesn't save it, so you have to specify that the operation should be performed in-place

Answer (score 0):

In the code `df = df.loc[(df.some_column == 'filter'),] df.sort_values(by=['my_date']) print(dfolc)`, you are using `df.loc() df.sort_values()`, I'm not sure how that works.

In the seconf line, you are calling it correctly `df.loc().sort_values()`, which is the correct way. You don't have to use the `df.` notation twice.